# Video is not playing when visible in viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to play automatically when the video is partially visible on the view-port and same as once video is completely hidden i would like to stop playing. As of now its working fine only in window scroll.

The Problem is when video is completely visible on view port on page load the video is not playing, can anyone suggest what is the issue?

So the below code is not working properly:-

```
videojs("myPlayerID").ready(function() {
  var myPlayer = this;

  window.onscroll = checkIfVideoInView;

  function checkIfVideoInView() {
    if (isScrolledIntoView(myPlayerID)) {
      myPlayer.play();
    } else {
      myPlayer.pause();
    }
  }

  function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return (
      elemBottom > docViewTop &&
      elemTop < docViewBottom
    );
  } 
});
```

Codepen URL:-

https://codepen.io/burner/pen/bxbzmR

Comment: You need to attach this code in either stack overflow snippet or atleast in the link. Check the syntax that is suggested while putting up the question. Please edit.

Comment: Whatever function you call on `scroll` function, call it in  `window.onload` or `document.ready` also and see

Comment: The code in the link you provided is working fine. I do not see where the problem is.

Comment: @R.D, The problem is, video is not playing when video is visible in viewport after rendering the page. I agree, code is working in onscroll function

Comment: @AravindS, I tried whatever you suggested.
  `window.onscroll = checkIfVideoInView;
window.onload = checkIfVideoInView;` but its not working

Comment: @jinfy I meant that the video is playing in the link that you provided. Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `window.onload = checkIfVideoInView` it will try to start playing on load. Some browsers, like Chrome, require users to interact with a document before a video with sound can be played. This means that to get autoplay working in all cases you also need to add a `muted` attribute to the video html tag.

```
  <video id="myPlayerID" muted ...></video>
```

https://codepen.io/theaos/pen/BOBggq

Comment: Superb mate.. but user perspective video should be played with sound right?